# Link-only answers targetting SO documentation?

Tags: discussion, answers, documentation, etiquette, link-only-answers

Another user asked for an error #1009, and got [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38544938/1627055) to the documentation example. And the answer got flagged as being link-only. Does the policy for link-only answers apply if the link goes to SO documentation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think the destination of a link should affect our stance that good answers require a *bit* more effort than just providing a link.

While documentation does help to assure that link rot will be less of a problem, and that the overall experience someone is likely to have going to another resource will be good - self-contained answers are really one of our hallmarks.

In essence, while links to docs are probably 'safer' than others, we should treat it as a *supplementary* resource and still take a moment to write an extra sentence or two that points out what the reader should be looking to take away from the resource.

But as always *please* exercise common sense. There are some cases where the question is valid, and the best answer to it is "use the foo() function, here's some information on how it works." If anything else after that simply feels like useless fluff in order to satisfy some rule, well - there can be the occasional exception.

Comment: In the case of _anything else would feel like useless fluff_, it'd be useful to just be able to close the question with an option "covered in documentation". Because these questions are usually then also lack of research and not really worth retaining.

Comment: @bwoebi Not sure that applies everywhere. I've seen pretty great Python questions that describe some interesting constraints to be satisfied and show what the OP has tried, and the best answer happens to be "Oh, there's this module that ships with Python and does all of that for you that you've overlooked", Again, discretion is pretty paramount.

Comment: Oh, I agree. I mean in case the question is anyway of low-quality and not very likely to have people land on it from google (_usually_). In the rare instances this isn't the case, it should be the occasional exception as you said.

Comment: Hmm. While I was writing a response to one of the comments, it came to me that even here on SO documentation the linked example *can* be deleted, so the question becomes answered with a yes.

Comment: Most of the point of no external links is because the target can break without SO's control.  This is not the case here.  The reason you shouldn't just link to another SO answer with "the answer is here" is that we already have a mechanism (close as duplicate) for that.  I'm not sure what remaining arguments there are against link-only answers and what makes a link to a stable and comprehensive solution worse than copying it onto SO, other than your (unjustified above) assertion that this is so.  Maybe we need "closed: covered by documentation example", which would justify the position above.